# How to delete associated objects in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have domain classes in my grails app as follows. I want to do delete operation which is i am doing for the first time on associated objects, The delete operation
is explained below.

```
Attachment
----------
Class Attachment{
    static hasMany = [mailDrafts: MailDraft];
}

MailDraft
---------------
Class MailDraft{
    static hasMany = [attachments: Attachment]
    static belongsTo = Attachment

    Training training

    Boolean isSent
    String type

}

Training
--------------
Class Training{
    static hasMany = [attachments: Attachment]

    MailDraft infoDraft
    MailDraft reminderDraft

}

Trainer
------------
Class Trainer{
    MailDraft introMailDraft
}
```

I am running a batch process that deletes all the mailDrafts with flag 'isSent=true' and the attachments of that draft only

```
Case1: 

infoDraft (MailDraft  object)
-----------------------------
training: A training
attachments: [file1, file2]
isSent: true
type: 'info'

training: A training (Training  object)
-------------------------------------
attachments: [file1]
```

In the above example, The process should deletes the 'infoDraft' object and 'file2' attachment But not the attachment 'file1', Because the training 'A training' has got 'file1' attachment

```
Case2: 

introMailDraft (MailDraft  object)
-----------------------------
training: null
attachments: [file3]
isSent: true
type: 'intro'
```

In the above example, the process should delete 'introMailDraft' and also attachment 'file3' But in this case the training is null

In all the above cases, the association tables should be updated

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have conditional deletions based on properties of associated classes you will be best served by hooking into GORM events and implementing your logic there. For example:

```
class MailDraft {
    static hasMany = [attachments: Attachment]
    static belongsTo = Attachment

    Training training

    Boolean isSent
    String type

    def beforeDelete() {
      MailDraft.withNewSession {
        // examine state of this instance
        // and delete any related instances that meet my business logic requirements.
      }
    }
}
```

You can find out more in the [Advanced GORM](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#advancedGORMFeatures) section of the Grails documentation.

Comment: I am getting an error as follows "errors.GrailsExceptionResolver HibernateException occurred when processing reque
st: [GET] /mailDraft/deleteOrphanEmails
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Stacktrace fol
lows:"

Comment: Without seeing what you implemented it's difficult to say what you are doing wrong. It's possible you don't need the withNewSession based on the error message you are getting. Again, it depends on what you are doing in your implementation.

Comment: Yes, There was issue with the remove() method, I got the solution form here "http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Getting-ConcurrentModificationException-how-to-deal-with-it-td3178826.html". Now its working fine